# How to code a web page that displays timelapse photos

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gallery, timelapse

I´m just learning to code and hoping for some directions to learn more. I have a project where I´m using a Raspberry Pi and a Canon DSL camera to take a photo every 15 minute and then upload the files to dropbox. The files are named like this: Y/M/D-H/M/S.jpg. Folder structure on dropbox: Year/Month/Day.

I now would like to display these photos in a nice way on a web page. I want to show the latest taken photo as the start image. I then want to make a link menu where it is possible to go back in time and see earlier photos. Back/forward button to jump between the 15 minute interval images. Same with year and date, a step up/down in increments navigate a specific year and month.

Im attaching example to a website that displays what I want to achieve. I dont necessarily need it to be as fancy (like the preview image when scrubbing back in time).

What would be a simple way to achieve this. Preferably a technology/language that is well documented as I want to learn and modify. I would not be surprised if someone has already built something similar. Do I need to learn using a database like php/orMysql for this?

Example:
https://longyearbyen.kystnor.no/

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQU76.jpg)

I use Gphoto2 in a simple python script to setup the intervals and naming.
I use a curl command to upload to dropbox via custom app.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I think `Flask` would be a reasonably good fit for this. Here's the most complete tutorial I am aware of https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world

Comment: `pathlib` is great for parsing directories of images, see https://pymotw.com/3/pathlib/index.html